Zombienet js script weird behaviour
I got the latest binary of polkadot(v1.10.0) by running zombienet setup and set up the following test files:
0001-network.toml
[settings]
timeout = 1000

[relaychain]
default_image = "{{POLKADOT_IMAGE}}"
chain = "rococo-local"
command = "polkadot"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  validator = true

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  validator = true

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"

0001-network.zndsl
Description: Block production smoke test
Network: ./0001-network.toml
Creds: config

alice: is up
bob: is up


alice: js-script ./0002-native-transfer.js return is 0 within 200 seconds

The js script:
const BOB = "5HpG9w8EBLe5XCrbczpwq5TSXvedjrBGCwqxK1iQ7qUsSWFc";

async function run(nodeName, networkInfo, _jsArgs) {
  const { wsUri, userDefinedTypes } = networkInfo.nodesByName[nodeName];
  const api = await zombie.connect(wsUri, userDefinedTypes);

  await zombie.util.cryptoWaitReady();

  // account to submit tx
  const keyring = new zombie.Keyring({ type: "sr25519" });
  const alice = keyring.addFromUri("//Alice");

  const call = api.tx.balances.transferKeepAlive(BOB, 10n**6n);
  const sudo = api.tx.sudo.sudo(call);

  await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const unsub = await sudo.signAndSend(alice, (result) => {
      console.log(`Current status is ${result.status}`);
      if (result.status.isInBlock) {
        console.log(
          `Transaction included at blockHash ${result.status.asInBlock}`
        );
      } else if (result.status.isFinalized) {
        console.log(
          `Transaction finalized at blockHash ${result.status.asFinalized}`
        );
        unsub();
        return resolve();
      } else if (result.isError) {
        console.log(`Transaction error`);
        unsub();
        return resolve();
      }
    });
  });

  return 0;
}

module.exports = { run };

And I am continously getting the following error:
 Error running script: ./0001-network.js     Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isEmpty')

I am using the latest zombienet version(1.3.100, but I did try with other version as well). I also tried running this on an other device.. still getting the same error.
The problematic line seems to be await sudo.signAndSend(alice, (result) => {.
I also tried to do something other than making a transfer, like getting the block number.
That is working but I am getting an incorrect result: 1,713,290,466,001, while the actual block number is less than 10.
Interacting with the chain through the polkadotjs UI works without a problem.

Hi @Szegoo, thanks for reporting this. I creates this issue to tracking in the repo (https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/1773). I will be updating there and reply with the fix here. Thanks!

The issue was caused by specifying the header types in the zombienet file:
[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"

This was overriding the types used by polkadot-js. Given that these types are not correct for the Rococo runtime, this was causing the error.
Removing the header types resolved the issue.
Related zombienet issue: https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/1773
